# op amp two feedback

Tags: feedback

[image][image: op amps feedback]

Hi

this circuit have two feedback.input signal is an exponential.amplitude is about .7v and 1/4 4066  switch connect a segment from op amp output.pin 6 connect to a puls and connect a segment from exponential signal to pin inverting from tl062.
why posetive feedback add to this circuit.
pleas explain how work this circuit

Comment: What do you mean by an "exponential signal?" What is going on around pins 6-9 on the right?

Comment: From first glance I would say that if the input "exponential signal" is produced by a perfect voltage source (with zero input resistance), it cannot be applied directly to the inverting input...

Comment: It's an incomplete circuit - please post a proper circuit with unambiguous connections.

Comment: But really, if the input source has some internal resistance RIN, there are two feedbacks... and both they are negative. The first is applied to the inverting input by the resistor network RIN-R17; the second is applied (when the switch 4066 is closed) to the non-inverting input through the inverting integrator at the bottom and the voltage divider R14-R18. But I have no idea why...

Answer (score 3):

That is a switched zero-offset circuit. It is intended to be used like this:

The input signal is applied through a resistor which you have failed to include. The circuit uses two phases - a zero phase and a measurement phase.

During the zero phase, the input is set to whatever constitutes "zero" signal. Since there is some sort of "exponential" processing going on, this is not exactly zero volts. At the same time, the 4066 is forced closed. Then D6B will operate to drive the D4 output to zero, or at least whatever the D6B input offset voltage is, call it 5 mV. After an appropriate interval to allow the output to settle, the measurement phase occurs.

During measurement phase, the signal to be measured is applied to D4, and the 4066 is driven open. With no input, the output of D6B will drift, but the drift rate is very low, since the input bias current of a TL061 is typically 5 pA, which combines with a feedback capacitor of 100 nF to produce a nominal drift rate of .05 mV/sec. Since the LF357 is fairly fast, the measurement can be taken quite soon after the measurement phase begins, and the offset loop will not be allowed to drift far. The effect is enhanced by the R18/R14 network, which reduces the apparent drift rate at D4 by a factor of more than 100. The actual drift rate, of course, will be somewhat greater than calculated, due to capacitor leakage and PCB stray resistances, but it should be very small - although it will be greatly influenced by things like fingerprints left on the PCB during assembly, and the quality of the flux-removal process used after soldering. The result of all of this will be to effectively remove the offset level applied during the zero phase.

The process will be repeated regularly, so as to give the zero phase as much time to settle to the current zero level as possible. As a result, the offset removal process will track things like temperature variations, which would otherwise have to be painstakingly removed before each measurement.